# ¿Cómo arreglo este PopUp? HTML + CSS

Tags: html, css

me encuentro haciendo una web y la verdad nunca tuve conocimientos de hacer pop ups, entonces me puse a buscar y mas o menos tengo lo que quiero pero me da un problema..

Éste es el div del pop up

```
<div class="modal-wrapper" id="popup">
    <div class="popup-contenedor">

        <h2>Esta es nuestra ubicaci&oacute;n!</h2>
        <iframe src="ACÁ LA URL DEL IFRAME QUE LA QUITO POR PRIVACIDAD" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <a title="Pulse aqu&iacute; para cerrar" class="popup-cerrar" href="#footer-wrapper"><i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Acá tengo la etiqueta  que llamaría al pop up

```
                                        <li class="icon fa-home"><a title="Mostrar ubicaci&oacute;n en google maps" href="#popup" class="popup-link">
                                            UBICACIÓN
                                        </li>
```

Y acá tengo el CSS

```
#popup {
   visibility: hidden;
   opacity: 0;
   margin-top: -300px;
}
#popup:target {
   visibility:visible;
   opacity: 1;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
   position: fixed;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0;
   margin:0;
   z-index: 999;
   transition:all 1s;
}
.popup-contenedor {
   position: relative;
   margin:7% auto;
   padding:30px 50px;
   background-color: #fafafa;
   color:#333;
   border-radius: 3px;
   width:50%;
}
a.popup-cerrar {
   position: absolute;
   top:10px;
   right:10px;
   background-color: white;
   padding:7px 10px;
   font-size: 30px;
   text-decoration: none;
   line-height: 1;
   color: red;
}
```

Ahora, el problema radica en que el DIV del pop up, me deja un espacio en blanco en el footer de la web digamos...

Algo así...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá bajamos un poco la barrita y está el espacio en blanco

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si le quito el DIV del pop up se vé normal el footer (obviamente no andaría el pop up)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y acá una imágen del pop up abierto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Censuro algunas cosas porque son datos reales**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema radica en la propiedad `visibility` de css, lo cual no muestra el elemento en la pagina pero **si ocupa espacio**.

Reemplaza `visibility:hidden` por `display:none`

Su comportamiento es el mismo con la diferencia que `display:none` **no ocupa espacio** en la pagina.

Para mostrar el elemento, usa `display:block` o `display:inline-block` en lugar de `visibility:visible`

```
#popup {
   display: none;
   opacity: 0;
   margin-top: -300px;
}
#popup:target {
   display:block;
   opacity: 1;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
   position: fixed;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0;
   margin:0;
   z-index: 999;
   transition:all 1s;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funcionó a la perfección, ¿ahora, me dices como puedo desactivar el scroll cuando esté abierto el popup y que te deje usar el scroll cuando el popup esté cerrado?

Con Scroll me refiero a subir y bajar la página (barra gris de la derecha)